# How to convert MediaStream to data in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is there a way to convert MediaStream image data into a Matrix type variable without going the canvas-context2d-getImageData() route?

For instance if I want to receive a WebRTC stream on a server for image processing, I cannot `import 'dart:html';` to create either a `VideoElement` or a `CanvasElement` so how do I tap those streams as usable data?

Comment: It just depends on the encoding of that WebRTC stream. Look into the protocol specification and parse it yourself.

Comment: Working on that. Was just hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: I think this might have been what I was looking for: http://gmandyam.github.io/image-capture/